# Selectively encoding HTML, how?

Tags: php, regex, html-entities

Allow me to explain my problem by before and after...

I have a comment system on a web community. Users can type in anything they want in a textarea, including special characters and HTML tags. In MySQL, I store the comment body exactly as typed, without any intervention. However, upon display I use HTML entities to prevent users from messing with HTML:

```
<?= nl2br(htmlentities($comment['body'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) ?>
```

This is working fine. However, I am now trying to enrich the comment system by automatically converting some links that are placed inside comments into richer objects. This concerns a photo forum and sometimes users make references to other photos by pasting in URLs in the comments:

> 'http://www.jungledragon.com/image/12/eagle.html

Using regular expressions, I am replacing valid links like the above into markup. In this case, it would be replaced with an img tag so that instead of a link, users see a thumb of that image directly inline in the comment.

The replacement is working fine. However, since I am using htmlentities, the replacement markup will render as text, rather than a rendered image. No surprises here.

**My question is, how can I selectively html encode a comment body? I want these links replacements to not be escaped, but everything else should be escaped.**

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there is no need to use `htmlentities()` here. It will needlessly convert non-ASCII UTF characters into their entities, making them take up to four times as much space, and causing trouble when searching. `htmlspecialchars()` will do.

Comment: Here's an idea, you know the htmlentity for < and > so you could do a regex search for &ltimg...&gt and replace that with your actual <img...>. Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the htmlentities first and the replacing afterwords.

Comment: Right after posting my question and thinking over this, I came to the same conclusion. I am making this way too difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you'd use a library to sanitize the HTML instead. A few are listed here:

http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Comment: That's a different thing, though. By my reading of the question, the users are typing text which is to be augmented, not actual HTML markup. If they type `<a>` then it is expected that less-than-A-greater-than will appear on the page.